# Full solution of $OA$

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

[image: question]

I have a geometry problem that asks for the length of $OA$ if $PR = 7cm$. I already got $7$ $cm$ as the answer, but I am not satisfied because the book didn't provide a step by step solution. I need someone to expand the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonals in rectangle $OPQR$ are equal, therefore $OQ=PR=7$ and also $OQ$ is radius too, thus $OA=7$

Answer (score 0):

Recognize diagonals and radii are all  equal

$$ OQ=PR= OA=OB = \sqrt {OP^2+PQ^2} =\sqrt {OR^2+QR^2} $$